# Get Fhir practitioners not assigned to any organization

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I am writing a web select component that allows users to browse through and select a practitioner from a pool of practitioners who have not been assigned to an organization.

The backend is based on hapi fhir server.

One way I can do this is fetch all practitioner, and practitioner resources and on the client side compute which practitioners conform to the above requirements.

Another approach is to find a concise request that would fetch practitioners not linked to any organization, and have the computation handled server side.The request should ideally cover these cases

1. practitioners who are not referenced by a practitionerRole and
2. practitioners who may be referenced by a practitionerRole that does not reference an organization.

Solutions I had tried was something along the lines of:
`http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Practitioner?_has:PractitionerRole:pracitioner:organization:missing=true`

but this does errors out with     `"diagnostics": "HAPI-1209: Unknown parameter name: PractitionerRole:organization:missing"`

How should the request in the second approach look like?